# Simpliest solution to check if File exists on a webserver. (Swift)

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection

There are a lot of discussion about this and I understand the solution to use the delegate method and check the response "404":

```
var request : NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

var connection : NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
connection.start()

    func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
//...
}
```

But I would like to have a simple solution like:

```
var exists:Bool=fileexists(sURL);
```

Because I will have a lot of request in the same class with the delegate and I only want to check the response with my function fileexists().

Any hints ?

**UPDATE**
I guess I'll have to do a synchronious request like the following, but I get always 0x0000000000000000 as a response::

```
   let urlPath: String = sURL;
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var request1: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    var response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?
    >=nil
    var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
    var dataVal: NSData =  NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request1, returningResponse: response, error:nil)!
    var err: NSError
    println(response)
```

Comment: If you want a very elegant solution in Swift and don't mind learning, check out this presentation on functional techniques, the presenter used an example very similar to yours.  http://www.meetup.com/nsmeetup/events/221685636/

Comment: Network request can take a long time, and the default timeout of NSURLConnection is 30 seconds. If you wrap it into a plain function call then it  could *block* the current thread for that time ...

Comment: Thanks for helping. At meetup I have to register myself. I am not a fan of registering in websites I don't know :-) I think about it.

Comment: @Martin E. Thanks for helping. But the request will take only some miliseconds. When downloading the file itself I have to implement this with the delegate for sure, but for checking if the file exists too ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking if a resource exists on a server requires sending a HTTP
request and receiving the response. TCP communication can take some
amount of time, e.g. if the server is busy, some router between the
client and the server does not work
correctly, the network is down etc.

That's why asynchronous requests are always preferred. Even if you think
that the request should take only milliseconds, it might sometimes be
seconds due to some network problems. And – as we all know – blocking
the *main thread* for some seconds is a big no-no.

All that being said, here is a possible implementation for a
`fileExists()` method. You should not use it on the main thread,
you have been warned!

The HTTP request *method* is set to "HEAD", so that the server sends
only the response header, but no data.

```
func fileExists(url : NSURL!) -> Bool {

    let req = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    req.HTTPMethod = "HEAD"
    req.timeoutInterval = 1.0 // Adjust to your needs

    var response : NSURLResponse?
    NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(req, returningResponse: &response, error: nil)

    return ((response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? -1) == 200
}
```

Comment: This works for most of the webservers, but I have that URL and if I check it the response is always nil. I tried with HEAD, GET, POST and TRACE for HTTPMethod, but still it's nil. If I remove the the HTTPMethod setter for the request, then I get a responce object (Of course without the important status code) so my question is how to check for a file on that kind of webserver? Thanks

Comment: I'm having trouble converting this (Martin R) to Swift 5. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 10):

Swift 3.0 version of  [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r)'s answer written asynchronously (the main thread isn't blocked):

```
func fileExistsAt(url : URL, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let checkSession = Foundation.URLSession.shared
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
    request.timeoutInterval = 1.0 // Adjust to your needs

    let task = checkSession.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let httpResp: HTTPURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            completion(httpResp.statusCode == 200)
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: In Swift 4.0 the following minor improvements are possible: func fileExistsAt(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) { let checkSession = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
        request.timeoutInterval = 1.0 // Adjust to your needs

        let task = checkSession.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let httpResp = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                completion(httpResp.statusCode == 200)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }

Answer (score 0):

Improved [Vito's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40593510/2177402) so the completion is always called:

```
func fileExists(at url: URL, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
    request.timeoutInterval = 1.0 // Adjust to your needs
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { _, response, _ in
        completion((response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200)
    }.resume()
}

// Usage
fileExists(at: url) { exists in
    if exists {
        // do something
    }
}
```

---

`async/await`

```
func fileExists(at url: URL) async throws -> Bool {
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
    request.timeoutInterval = 1.0 // Adjust to your needs
    let (_, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    return (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200
}

// Usage
if try await fileExists(at: url) {
    // do something
}

// or if you don't want to deal with the `throw`
if (try? await fileExists(at: url)) ?? false {
    // do something
}
```