# Fixing NSURLConnection Deprecation from Swift 1.2 to 2.0

Tags: swift, xcode7, swift2, ios9

I have a function written in Swift 1.2, that checks for Reachability of Address or IP. Here it is :

```
func isHostConnected(hostAddress : String) -> Bool
{
    var response : NSURLResponse?
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: hostAddress)!)
    request.timeoutInterval = 3

    let data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: nil)

    return ((response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)!.statusCode == 200)
}
```

Now since, `NSURLConnection` is deprecated, as per Xcode suggestion I tried writing it using `NSURLSession.dataTaskWithRequest`, here it is :

```
func isHostConnected(hostAddress : String) -> Bool
{
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: hostAddress.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)!)
    request.timeoutInterval = 3

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: nil, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

    var responseCode = -1

    session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data : NSData?, response : NSURLResponse?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
        responseCode = (response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)!.statusCode
    })!.resume()

    return (responseCode == 200)
}
```

Above code always returns **false** (its Obvious), since `completionHandler` gets executed on seperate Thread.

My concern is that, can I make `completionHandler()` run on MainThread somehow like `sendSynchronousRequest` does by blocking it.

I have reasons to not to use 'Apple's Reachabilty' here.

Any suggestion will be helpful. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(Repeating my arguments from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30670518/1187415:)

> Checking if a resource exists on a server requires sending a HTTP
>   request and receiving the response. TCP communication can take some
>   amount of time, e.g. if the server is busy, some router between the
>   client and the server does not work correctly, the network is down
>   etc.
>
> That's why asynchronous requests are always preferred. Even if you
>   think that the request should take only milliseconds, it might
>   sometimes be seconds due to some network problems. And – as we all
>   know – blocking the main thread for some seconds is a big no-no.

That being said, you can use a "counting semaphore" or a "dispatch group" to wait for the completion of some asynchronous task. 
You should *not* use this on the main thread. Blocking the main thread
for up to 3 seconds is not acceptable!

```
func isHostConnected(hostAddress : String) -> Bool
{
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: hostAddress.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)!)
    request.timeoutInterval = 3
    request.HTTPMethod = "HEAD"

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    var responseCode = -1

    let group = dispatch_group_create()
    dispatch_group_enter(group)

    session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(_, response, _) in
        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            responseCode = httpResponse.statusCode
        }
        dispatch_group_leave(group)
    })!.resume()

    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    return (responseCode == 200)
}
```

Remarks:

- Setting the HTTP method to "HEAD" is a small optimization, as the
  server sends only the response header without the actual data.
- In the case of a illegal host name, `response` would be `nil`, and
  `responseCode = (response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)!.statusCode` would crash.

Comment: Woww.. I wasn't aware of something like `dispatch_group`, will surely explore this & thnxxx a lot, @Martin.