# Best practice to replace a synchronous NSURLConnection with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

As

```
NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:&connectionError
```

is set deprecated I will have to replace an Importer I wrote a long time ago.

The Importer does the following:

1. It fetches data from API-A. The data there can be on multiple pages.
2. It uses the data from the first fetch (also multipage) to query data from API-B and merges
3. Results from the API-B query will be merged with data from API-A

I implemented this with a background-operation where I use methods for each API which called recursively if there are  mulitple pages for the request.

But as NSURLSession does not support synchronous request I currently only see the option to have lot of overhead (e.g. iVars) control what's called in the completion block (e.g. next Page or start to query API-B).

So, what would be an elegant solution to bring this to NSURLSession.

NB: Just to make sure, my previous solution does not block the main thread at all. But back then it was the easiest way to control the merge of two sources.

Comment: Here is your answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/30952732/2713079

Comment: I dont understand that why you require synchronous call.. As per normal conventions, Webservicecalls always should be asynchronous. If you want to keep user waiting then.. put one HUD/ActivityIndicator which shows device is fetching the results.. calling any web api synchronously is not a good idea. So as per my suggestion go via asynchronous call

Comment: As I mentioned above, I do the import on a background thread so there is neither blocking UI nor some progress-Indicator visible.
And the reason why I used the synchronous method (again, the way I used it it is not blocking anything!) is that I have to wait for an unknown amount of data which comes from an unknown amount of requests. And ther the synchronous method allowed me to handle that much better than keeping a lot of overhead to handle asynchronous requests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer is not supposed to be best practice. It was just practical for me.

Faced with the situation when a bunch of synchronous requests is executed in background and the order of execution matters I've ended up using the following:

SyncRequestSender.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SyncRequestSender : NSObject

+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                 returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response
                             error:(NSError **)error;

@end
```

SyncRequestSender.m

```
#import "SyncRequestSender.h"

@implementation SyncRequestSender

+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                 returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response
                             error:(NSError **)error
{
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_group_enter(group);


    NSError __block *err = NULL;
    NSData __block *data;
    NSURLResponse __block *resp;

    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                     completionHandler:^(NSData* _data, NSURLResponse* _response, NSError* _error) {
        resp = _response;
        err = _error;
        data = _data;
        dispatch_group_leave(group);

    }] resume];

    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    if (response)
    {
        *response = resp;
    }
    if (error)
    {
        *error = err;
    }

    return data;
}

@end
```

Comment: use `dispatch_semaphore_wait` is better I think.

Comment: @KleinMioke considered using that but for some reason decided to play with dispatch groups.

Answer (score 2):

This's an example in `AFNetworking`, it shows how to wait an asynchronous task.

```
- (NSArray *)tasksForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath {
    __block NSArray *tasks = nil;
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    [self.session getTasksWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *dataTasks, NSArray *uploadTasks, NSArray *downloadTasks) {
        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(dataTasks))]) {
            tasks = dataTasks;
        } else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(uploadTasks))]) {
            tasks = uploadTasks;
        } else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(downloadTasks))]) {
            tasks = downloadTasks;
        } else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(tasks))]) {
            tasks = [@[dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks] valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.self"];
        }

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    return tasks;
}
```